# swagger integration to document spring rest APIs

Tags: http-status-code-404, integration, swagger-ui, status

I am trying to integrate swagger to my application to document my rest APIs.
My application is not *Maven* dependent so I included all required *jars* manually.

After changes have been made, hitting */v2/api-docs* doesn't return any JSON output but a 404 response instead.
Hitting */swagger-ui.html* a page with swagger header prompts an alert box continuously with a message saying:

> "Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:

Thank you.

Comment: Formatted, rephrased, grammar corrections.